# Magento - Importing Products in csv file - empty columns

Tags: magento, csv, import

I am currently adding all my products into a csv file ready to import into my store. To get the template i exported my existing products and am using that csv as the template which contains every single column.

I have a lot of empty columns such as...

`custom_design_from` `manufacturer` `minimal_price` `msrp` `special_price`

etc..

Do i need to include these empty columns? If i remove them will that mess up my import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it will not effect , you can remove them from csv and import

Comment: can you please tell me why the answer in not satisfactory

Comment: @karthik OP asks "Do I need to include these empty columns?", Rohit answers "no", it looks like an answer to me... we may argue the relevance of the question, but that's another question

Answer (score 2):

No it will not mess up your import, however be careful when making edits to the csv file as some programs save the file in the wrong csv format I'd recommend open office and when you hit save make sure you push in current format